# how to get current location latitude and longitude

Tags: android

i am trying to get current location latitude and longitude using the code below but it force close and display in log cat "`null pointer exception`" so pls check where i am wrong..my cod is below...

Comment: at which line is that exception occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if the null pointer exception really happens within the `if()` block, at the `getLatitude()` call, this means the reference to the Location object that you just tested is no longer valid.

So I would try to copy the location object before using it, like this:

```
       public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Location copyOfLocation = new Location(location);
            updateWithNewLocation(copyOfLocation );
        }
```

Haven't tested this, and I don't remember seeing this problem before...

--Edit--

Wait, the exception has moved since your last edit... Well your location is null probably because the system has no previous location to give you. Try going outside with your phone, power on the GPS, launch Google Maps until the GPS icon in the notification bar does not blink anymore, quit Maps, go back inside and try your app again.

-- Edit 2--

There are two conditions for [getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) to work:

- the location provider must be powered on (must use the Android preferences panel to turn the GPS on)
- the system must have computed a position with the required provider sometime in the past

Else it will return null

Comment: @stephen,Mathew http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250597/find-current-location-latitude-and-longitude why this link code was not working????same problem and soln provided by john nick is also not working?why?

Comment: can any one pls provide me the running code of this qus..means getting current position lat and lond and change lat long when position changed

Comment: it is possible to get current position latitude and longitude on emulator???if yes then what setting is required in emulator????

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator