# getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) returns NULL

Tags: android

I am  new to Android and I am trying to write one test app which should display the latitude and longitude of the current location. Right Now, I am using Android Emulator to do so.  This is the code I am using.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

But the location object returns `NULL` rather than some mock location. I have added the permission in manifest too.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

How can I achieve this Android emulator?

Comment: Got the answer.refer this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250597/find-current-location-latitude-and-longitude

Answer (score 3):

you have to telnet to your instance emulator and put the following:

```
telnet localhost 5554
geo fix <lat> <lng>
```