# How to get the current latitude and longitude in Android Application?

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I want to find latitude and longitude of my current location in android application.Its not on location changed .i got the latitude and longtitude value while location Changed.but i need the Current location of latitude and longitude.How to do this?

Comment: Have you Googled at all for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17857993/1318946

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read Android document for [Obtaining User Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html)

Answer (score -2):

```
Location location=manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);//
location.getLatitude();
location.getLongitude();
```