# google Maps v2 API for android location return null

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

Hi I need some help with this, I have already looked and try many different things. I'm trying to get my current location on android but since the location comes back null my app crashes. I really need help with this please.

I don't know if I'm being clear in here but everytime I call getLastKnownlocation it comes back null, so when I try to get the double lat= location.getLatitude() same for the longitude it won't return anything and there is where my app crashes.

Help...
Here a piece of code

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

double lat = location.getLatitude();
double lng = location.getLongitude();
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
```

at latitude is where it stops.

Comment: what provider do you get at  

 String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);?

Comment: there never has to be a location returned to you so you MUST ALWAYS check for a null location

Comment: @CAA The provider I get is GPS on this line

Comment: Try to add the `findLocation` method in your `Mainactivity`, please refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9873478/4186942)

Answer (score 1):

Do you retrieve the GoogleMap object from the fragment before calling those functions?

Something like:

```
//get map fragment from the static layout (in this case it has id = "map")
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
//get GoogleMap object, then you can start using it, for example enabling the location
    map = mapFragment.getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Yeah @Andrea Montanari it's being call, infact my maps opens up well with no problem, but that's just before I code it to get the current location. to be more clear if I just do this: MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); it wil open and point where I am but if I try to get the current location so the camera can move to the point I am this comes back null and make my app crash.

Comment: Did you add the required permission to retrieve the position?

Comment: Yeah I have added all of them: 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Ok, then I suggest you to do the following: in my working code I do these steps:

      gps = new GPSTracker(this);
         if(gps.canGetLocation()){
         //retrieve coordinates
         double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
         double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
         latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);  
         //zoom in the map by level 16
         
         map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 16)); 

You can see GPSTracker class from https://github.com/andreamontanari/android/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help I appreciate it, I have already solved my problem.
Here a piece of code that helped me get ti done:

```
//I needed to have this line before everything else for me to get my current 
//location from getLastKnownLocation method.

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet"));

//And the all the codes I had before
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

double lat = location.getLatitude();
double lng = location.getLongitude();
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
             .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
             .title("Here"));
```