# Android location is always null with both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER

Tags: android, geolocation

This the Service class that I'm trying to use from my MainActivity.java. Running on emulator.

```
package com.example.sonia.project;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker() {
    }

    public Location getLocation(Context mContext) {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("Location", "Location changed!");
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is my onStart() method of MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    gps = new GPSTracker();
    gps.getLocation(this);
}
```

And then I call getLocation() again on a button click in MainActity

```
gps.getLocation(this);
```

The accepted answer on this question suggests getting location updates and using multiple providers - [My current location always returns null. How can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873190/my-current-location-always-returns-null-how-can-i-fix-this). I'm doing both.

getLocation() always returns a null location, even if I try to get the location after several minutes. What can do to make it return a valid location and not null?

Comment: Your testing on Emulator or Real device?

Comment: emulator - Nexus 5 API 22 x86

Comment: if you din't got your answer use fusedLocation "javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider" here is the example

Answer (score 0):

To get Location in emulator you have to configure through emulator control

For more information refer following link

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-gps-with-locationmanager-to-get-current-location-example/

Comment: In my emulator, Settings > Location shows that it's ON, and Settings > Location > Location mode shows that it's using "High Accuracy" mode (Use GPS, Wi-Fi, and cellular networks to determine location). However, I'm not able to find the Eclipse > DDMS (Perspective) setting in Android Studio. From your link, it looks like a hack anyway, the emulator is not detecting the location, but reading hardcoded values that you fed it.