# How to put value of getLatitude() into textview

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I am developing an app that whenever you click on the get location (gpsBtn), GPS will be enabled and the Location of the user will be shown in a TextView. I get java.lang.NullPointerException error,the app has stops unexpectedly. How do I fix this?

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public LocationManager lm;
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, new MyLocationListener());
            Button gpsBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getLocation);
            gpsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showCurrentLocation();
                }
            });

        public void showCurrentLocation() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));

        }
        class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }
```

Android manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mehrdad.myapplication" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: check my answer and let me know,it work for you or not.

Comment: @DeepakGoyal its not work..

Comment: @DeepakGoyal please help me..

Comment: @DeepakGoyal help me again..please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try.....move your `final TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);` to the `onCreate()` method. Also add `textView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));` line inside the try and catch block.

```
try{
 textView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
}catch(Exception e){
  // exception occurs......
}
```

**FULL CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public LocationManager lm;
        TextView textView;
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, new MyLocationListener());
            textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            Button gpsBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getLocation);
            gpsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showCurrentLocation();
                }
            });

        public void showCurrentLocation() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            try{
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            }catch(Exception e){
              // exception occurs......
            }
        }
        class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }
```

Comment: can you add textView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())); inside the try and catch block?
i cant..

Comment: check my updated answer. and if still not work, can you post your logcat error....

Comment: no need to declare the textview final. Just do as of my answer. Let it try first.

Comment: i didnt get any error
but not show anything in textview

Comment: it means your location.getLatitude() returs null or empty string.

Comment: System.out.println("Location is "+location.getLatitude());
and tell me what is the output.

Comment: it means it does not give the location latitude.

Comment: getLastKnownLocation returns null if any Location has been acquired from the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: you can show the current location of user if it gives null.

Comment: see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873190/my-current-location-always-returns-null-how-can-i-fix-this