# Lack of GPS accuracy resulting in null pointer

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-location, locationmanager

ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATON have both been included in the manifest. Also included in the Activity are:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
```

I have a listener for the nav drawer with the following class

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null)
        {
            final double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

    selectItem(position);
    }
}
```

From this, the `location = null`, and thus would fail on `location.getLongitude();`. I can of course avoid this with `if (location != null)`, but I want the `lat` and `long` found.

Why is the location always null?

Comment: Do you target API 23 or higher? Where do you [request permission at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Finding the location is not a easy task on the hardware side. You can't tell the device I wanna know my location so give it to me right now! It needs to observe some data from GPS satellites if outside with clear visibility, otherwise it uses other available options like wifi. Untill your device come up with a valid location, you should wait. I recommend you to observe `onLocationChanged` event and update your listview when this event occurs. Also it is good to use `null` condition untill it detect your location.

Comment: We've had heavy snowstorms for the past few days. Could this be the cause?

Comment: Even for the best case, if u use location directly, you most probably get null data. So that s why you should wait onLocationChanged event

Comment: Yes, the solution is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873190/my-current-location-always-returns-null-how-can-i-fix-this. Mods jumping the gun closing it

Comment: I also recommend FusedLocationProviderApi to get the best available solution https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi