# Android - java.lang.NullPointerException - Google Maps

Tags: java, android

I try to display the user's latitude but I get an error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference.

GPS is well activated and is the "bestprovider".

```
public void getUserPosition()
{
    /**************Vérification des droits localisation******************/
    Context mainContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mainContext,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    Log.e("Droits Position : ", String.valueOf(permissionCheck));

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mainContext,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this.getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        {
            Log.e("LOCATION : ", "Localisation acceptée !");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("LOCATION : ", "Localisation refusée !");

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mainContext,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
    Log.e("DROITS :", String.valueOf(permissionCheck));
    /*****************FIN vérification droits localisation************/

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mainContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //On ajoute des critère pour trouver le meilleur provider (indicateur de position)
    Criteria critere = new Criteria();
    critere.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);//On demande une position précise
    critere.setAltitudeRequired(false);         // Est-ce que le fournisseur doit être capable de donner une altitude ?
    critere.setBearingRequired(false);           // Est-ce que le fournisseur doit être capable de donner une direction ?
    critere.setCostAllowed(true);              // Est-ce que le fournisseur peut être payant ?
    critere.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH); //On accepte d'utiliser un provider a haute consommation électrique(GPS)
    critere.setSpeedRequired(false); // Est-ce que le fournisseur doit être capable de donner une vitesse ?


    List<String> providers = locationManager.getAllProviders(); //Liste des fournisseurs qui correspondent
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(critere, true); //Le provider qui répond le mieux aux critères

    if(bestProvider == null) //On affiche le nom du provider choisis
    {
        Log.e("Best Provider : ","NULL !");
    }
    else{
        Log.e("Best Provider : ", bestProvider);
    }

    Location positionNow = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider); //Objet location qui contient la position de l'utilisateur
    Log.e("Position user now", "Lat:"+String.valueOf(positionNow.getLatitude()));

}
```

---

Comment: `Location` is `null`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873190/my-current-location-always-returns-null-how-can-i-fix-this

Comment: Please debug your code!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `getLastKnownLocation()` which can return null.. refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9873351/886001) to better handle the last known location

You can also refer to the [Location API documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#GetLocation) to use `getLastLocation` which accordingly may rarely return also null if no location is found