# location returns null when started the first time

Tags: java, android

For my app, I need to get the location of the user, to fetch corresponding data from a server. The problem is that the code I use doesn't properly return the location when it's opened the first time. After restarting the app once it works just fine. I searched the other questions and found out, that if you use `getLastKnownLocation` and there is no location since the last reboot, it returns null. But why does it work when the app is restarted? Does it fetch it when it's opened the first time, and how can I make it wait until the location is fetched properly at the first opening then?

The code of my MainActivity:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

  requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);
} else {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    GPSClass gt = new GPSClass(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Location location = gt.getLocation();

    if (location == null) {
       //Toast
    } else {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
    }
    new GetContacts().execute();
}
```

And the GPSClass:

```
public class GPSClass implements LocationListener {

Context context;

public GPSClass(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
}

public Location getLocation(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.e("fist","error");
        return null;
    }
    try {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (isGPSEnabled){
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000,10,this);
            Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            return loc;
        }else{
            Log.e("sec","error");
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873190/my-current-location-always-returns-null-how-can-i-fix-this

Comment: How can I notify my MainActivity when the location has changed in the GPS class?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the full tutorial](http://shaoniiuc.com/android/android-receiving-location-updates-kotlin/)

I shared a tutorial link follow that link.

Call this below method. It will return value; when lat and long is found. Until object is null or doesn't return any value your app must be idle or show some progress value or tell the user to wait.

```
InitGeoLocationUpdate.locationInit(SplashScreen.this,
    object -> {
        double latitude = object.latitude;
        double longitude = object.longitude;
        Lg.INSTANCE.d(TAG, "Current Location Latitude: " + latitude + " Longitude: " +
                longitude);
    });
```

Comment: How do I use this method inside a class (here the MainActivity) when the location is fetched in another class (in the GPSClass)?

Comment: Use this method anywhere. You can use it onResume method. It will best. Before calling the method make sure you implemented the runtime permission.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm actually not familiar with Kotlin, so can you tell me what I have to add to my GPS class so I can call the function in my activity?

Comment: This is a util class. Just copy paste it. Fuction that I added here,  call it from your onrResume function.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will try it! 
is there a difference in adding a normal class or a util class?

Comment: No differenc.  Util class is ur custom normal class. I just called that util class

Answer (score 0):

Try this this will not give you null current location

```
class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {

LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener mlocListenerTmp = new CustomLocationListener();
private final Handler mLocHandler;

public GetLastLocation(Handler mLocHandler) {
    this.mLocHandler = mLocHandler;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    timer.cancel();
    mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListenerTmp);
    Location location = mlocManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    {
        if (mlocListenerTmp != null) {
            mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListenerTmp);
        }
        currentLocation = location;
    }
    if (location != null) {
        String message = String.format(
            "Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
            location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
        Log.d("loc", " :" + message);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        {
            b.putBoolean("locationRetrieved", true);
            {
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                {
                    msg.setData(b);
                    mLocHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(
            "loc",
            ":No GPS or network signal please fill the location manually!");
        location = mlocManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            currentLocation = location;
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            {
                b.putBoolean("locationRetrieved", true);
                {
                    Message msg = Message.obtain();
                    {
                        msg.setData(b);
                        mLocHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            {
                b.putBoolean("locationRetrieved", false);
                {
                    Message msg = Message.obtain();
                    {
                        msg.setData(b);
                        mLocHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**call it like this in your `MainActivity`**

```
timer.schedule(new GetLastLocation(mLocHandler), 3000);
```

and the customLocationclass is as follows:

```
public class CustomLocationListener implements LocationListener {

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();
    currentLocation = loc;
    String Text = "My current location is: " + "Latitud = "
        + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();
    Log.d("loc", "onLocationChanged" + Text);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful! Do you think of having `class GetLastLocation` as an nested class or a spereate class?

Comment: I thought so, but after a few variants of trying I still have some compilation errors. I made a different class for the CustomLocationListener and the GetLastLocation class. I did all missing declarations and now in the MainActivity call `timer.schedule(new GetLastLocation(mLocHandler), 3000);` it says that the symbol cannot be resolved. Can you tell me what to do about it? How do I initialize it in the MainActivity as well?

Comment: just before the line of error add `Timer timer = new Timer();`

Comment: My apologies, I meant I have that issue of not being able to resolve `mLocHandler`, not the timer!

Comment: have you added the `GetLastLocation` Activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` of your project?

Comment: replace the error line with this `timer.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 3000);`... hope it works..

Comment: It can't be added, it says it `is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity` and it wouldn't have a default constructor, too. Do you think it would be necessary to add it?

Comment: its not neccessary... replace the `class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {` line to `public class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {` in the `GetLastLocation` class

Comment: I already did that, it didn't do the trick unfortunately. It still says `Cannot resolve symbol 'mLocHandler`

Comment: try putting the entire `GetLastLocation` class  into your `MainActivity` ... this will work.. surely...

Comment: That was my first question referring to, whether it should be a nested or a seperate class, so I already tried it. Even as a nested class I have the same error