# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Kotlin no error details in logocat

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hello I'm having an error when passing the same value from if to else the logcat doesn't give me more information just E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main, and points the line that contains the if and the else. could someone tell me how to fix it? any help is welcome.

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        Log.i("MAP READY", "READY")
      LINE ERROR  val position = if (currentLocation != null) LatLng(currentLocation!!.latitude, currentLocation!!.longitude) else  LatLng(currentLocation!!.latitude, currentLocation!!.longitude)
        this.map = googleMap
        this.map!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15f)) // Vienna
        getFineLocationPermission()
        this.map!!.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
        this.map!!.uiSettings.isRotateGesturesEnabled = true
        this.map!!.uiSettings.isZoomGesturesEnabled = true
        this.map!!.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this)
        this.map!!.setOnMapLongClickListener(this)


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using  [not-null assertion operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator) which will throw NPL if any of the value is null so your `currentLocation` is null which is throwing the exception.

```
val position = if (currentLocation != null) LatLng(currentLocation!!.latitude, currentLocation!!.longitude) else  LatLng(currentLocation!!.latitude, currentLocation!!.longitude)
```

here if the `currentLocation` is null then you are still using it inside `else` case which is clearly the root cause of exception (thrown by `!!`)

Either use dummy value(preferably fix the issue with currentLocation) or you can use safe call with `let` as [`.?let`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls)

```
currentLocation?.let{ // run if currentLocation is not null
    val position = LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude)
    //... code 
}
```

Comment: Hello, you could include in the answer how this line of code would be complete with the alternative you informed, thanks sorry to bother you. I'm a beginner

Comment: @YPLABS you need to fix `currentLocation` initialisation which is a different issue as using dummy location is an option for latlong but it's not a desired behaviour. `if (currentLocation != null) LatLng(currentLocation!!.latitude, currentLocation!!.longitude) else  LatLng(25.2744, 133.7751)/* dummy values*/`

Comment: yes but I need to pass the same value from the if to the else to both take the current location

Comment: @YPLABS you can use dummy values in `else` statement as shown in previous comment or you can use [getLastKnownLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9873351/4936904)