# Getting Current Location Longitude and Latitude without Change my Position

Tags: android, gps, location, latitude-longitude

I can find the current location latitude and longitude.But These data are not shown before change my current position.I want to get current location longitude and latitude without change my position.

```
package com.example.gps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MapView m;
Button b,b1,b2;
MapController mc;double l1;double l2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LocationManager mlocManager = 

        (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    boolean net = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Location l = null;
    if(net)
        l= mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(l!=null)
    {
        l1 = l.getLongitude();
        l2 = l.getLatitude();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),l1+".."+l2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(); 
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener); 


}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 

{ 

@Override 

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 

{ 

loc.getLatitude(); 

loc.getLongitude(); 

String Text = "My current location is: "+ 

"Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() + 

"Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude(); 



Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), 

Text, 

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

} 



@Override 

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 

{ 

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), 

"Gps Disabled", 

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show(); 

} 



@Override 

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 

{ 

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), 

"Gps Enabled", 

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

} 



@Override 

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 

{ 



} 

}
}
```

Since this code returns data from onLocationChanged(Location loc) method so i don't get data without change my location after install it on my device.But i need latitude ,longitude without change my location.Is it possible.Please give a solution

Comment: try getting Latitude n Longitude after requestLocationUpdates(...) u will get immediately

Comment: why not using lastKnownPosition? That should be offered by the LocationManager...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17857993/1318946

Answer (score 4):

try this code:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
      System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
      onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
      latituteField.setText("Location not available");
      longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
      System.out.println("Location not avilable");
    }
  }

  /* Request updates at startup */
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
  }

  /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
    double lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    Log.i(TAG, "Lattitude:" +lat);
    Log.i(TAG, "Longitude:" +lng);
  }
```

Comment: when i use this code for a new device it does not get anything.I think in this case getLastKnownLocation() method returns null.But i want current location latitude longitude when user login my app.i get data after moving my device but i need data without my location change.Please help me......