# how to get current location on google map

Tags: android

below is my code which give hardcoded lat long of user i want to show dynamic latlong where  ever user go map show current location of user how to do this
?

```
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_support_map_fragment);


    FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 SupportMapFragment supportmapfragment = (SupportMapFragment)fragment;
   GoogleMap supportMap = supportmapfragment.getMap();



   LatLng latLng = new LatLng(24.89337, 67.02806);
   supportMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
   supportMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
           .position(latLng)
           .title("My Spot")
           .snippet("This is my new spot!")

 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
   supportMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
   supportMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
   supportMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line:

```
supportMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to get the current location of the user. You need to use [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) to request continuous updates. You can specify the time interval or the distance interval between the location updates. This with give you a `Location` object from which you can extract the latitude and longitude. You can then use these 2 values to point the current location on the map. There are numerous questions and great answers on How to get the current location. You can start by reading:

[Location Strategies Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

Some of the previous questions are:

- [How to get Latitude and Longitude of the mobile device in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobiledevice-in-android?rq=1)
- [how to get longitude and latitude in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371932/how-to-get-longitude-and-latitude-in-android)
- [find current location latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250597/find-current-location-latitude-and-longitude)
- [How to get the current location latitude and longitude in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519198/how-to-get-the-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-android)

Hope this helps.